# Is it possible to distribute sensors over multiple computers?

Tags: physics, gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would like to simulate a number of robots (up to let's say 10) in real time, each with a significant sensor suite. Is it possible to distribute sensors as slaves to the physics simulation across multiple machines? If it's not right now, does the architecture readily support it? I could imagine a plugin to the main server to broadcast world changes, and a "fake" physics that passes that on to the local sensors on each slave machine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/293/is-it-possible-to-distribute-sensors-over-multiple-computers?/) by [Max Pfingsthorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/103/max-pfingsthorn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sensor simulation is currently not distributed. I've created a ticket for this:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/383/distributed-sensors

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) on 2021-06-23**:
Hi nkoenig. I wonder if there is any update on this. The ticket is still there.